# Is there a way to customize the job interface in Rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

I've been looking through the documentation some way to customize a job's interface but didn't find anything.

What I need:

- I have a multiselect option with many values. Is there a way to create foldable menus? I'd like to do something similar to the node selection interface.
- Is it possible to show or hide one multi-option field depending on another option value, dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible to create a custom [UI plugin](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/11-ui-plugins.html#ui-plugins) for your job. I made an [example](https://github.com/MegaDrive68k/plugins/blob/master/option-filter.zip) here based on cascading options ([here](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/wvZClHL_0Jw/m/nPOVNPPECgAJ) is the use case).

The key here is `main.js` file (at `/resources/js` inside the zip file) you can see a javascript function that "hide" a element based on your selection.

[Here](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/ui-plugin-examples) you have a generic example of a UI plugin.

Comment: Wow! [THIS](https://github.com/MegaDrive68k/plugins/blob/master/option-filter.zip) is exactly what I was looking for. Although the name of the fields in the XML and in the JS do not match but after a little editing it worked for me.

Now, is there a way of splitting a long multiselection list in several columns?

Comment: That's requested [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4934) please add your use-case to that thread.

Comment: I've already split the list into columns by changing the grid class into a custom one with JQuery and adding CSS in my plugin.

The last part of my issue is to have "foldable" menus. I'd like to have several checkboxes grouped into hiding menus, similar to the "Change target nodes" option. Is it possible to edit the UI to have something like this?