# Use cascade options on Rundeck job?

Tags: xml, yaml, rundeck

i would like to ask if is possible use rundeck with a cascade options input  viewer starting with dropdown option.
i had this dropdown and i would like, after selected some option appears different input options
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jdSw.png)

is possible to made that with rundeck job webgui ?

Best regards community

Comment: Yes it's possible, take a look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brundeck%5D+cascade

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to share with you what i want o made:

create a dynamic input variables using a dropdown option.

If select a dropdown value will be show some inputs variables. if i select another value in dropdown will show another input variables.

someone knows if this is possible to made in rundeck WEB GUI ?
Thank you
Best regards

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That's possible following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70111932/10426011) (basically is a kind of plugin that hides/change other text options based on the cascade selection).